# How to use delegates inside a static PowerShell class?

Tags: powershell, class, reflection, delegates

> **I want to use a func delegate in my static PowerShell 5.0 class:**

I had issues to find a way to assign other static class methods for my delegate.

This code is working but not very convinient.

Is there a better way to use a delegate here ?

And I need to instanciate my static! class, only to get the type.

I tried the outcommented line, how you would do it with .NET types, but it's not working for my own class.

How can I get the type of my static class here more elegant ?

And, BTW, GetMethod() did not accecpt the BindingFlags parameter, why ?

```
class Demo
{
    hidden static [object] Method_1([string] $myString)
    {
        Write-Host "Method_1: $myString"
        return "something"    
    }

    hidden static [object] Method_2([string] $myString)
    {
        Write-Host "Method_2: $myString"    
        return $null    
    }

    hidden static [object] TheWrapper([string]$wrappedMethod, [string] $parameter)
    {
        # do a lot of other stuff here... 

        #return [System.Type]::GetType("Demo").GetMethod($wrappedMethod).CreateDelegate([Func``2[string, object]]).Invoke($parameter)
        return [Demo]::new().GetType().GetMethod($wrappedMethod).CreateDelegate([Func``2[string, object]]).Invoke($parameter)    
    }

    static DoWork()
    {
        Write-Host ([Demo]::TheWrapper('Method_1', 'MyMessage'))
        [Demo]::TheWrapper('Method_2', 'c:\my_file.txt')
    }
}

[Demo]::DoWork()
```

Comment: `[Demo]::new().GetType()` -> `[Demo]`

Comment: first question answered, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an instance of `[demo]` since `[demo]` is the actual type of the class. Also, you can write the delegate type more simply as `[Func[string,object]]`. This simplifies the body of `TheWrapper` method to

```
return [Demo].GetMethod($wrappedMethod).CreateDelegate([Func[string, object]]).Invoke($parameter)
```

but a much simpler way to do this in PowerShell is to get the method by passing its name to the '.' operator then invoking the result:

```
return [demo]::$wrappedMethod.Invoke($parameter)
```

In PowerShell, the right-hand side of the '.' operator doesn't need to be a constant. You can use an expression that results in the name of the method (or property) to retrieve.

Comment: Is any particular reason to use `[demo]::$wrappedMethod.Invoke($parameter)` over `[demo]::$wrappedMethod($parameter)`?

Comment: Thank you so much :-) I always forget how simple you can achive such things in script languages, but isn't it a safer way to explicitly use a C# delegate ?